# Asciifolding not working Elastic Search Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, elasticsearch, non-ascii-characters

I am having a really bad time trying to get "**asciifolding**" working for my Rails app.
I want to search words containing "**accented**" characters for example i want "**foróige**" to come up when i search "**foroige**".
I have tried many things. A couple of them are below.

```
analysis: {
                analyzer: {
                    text: {
                        tokenizer: "standard",
                        filter: ["standard","lowercase", "asciifolding"],
                        char_filter: 'html_strip'
                    },
                    sortable: {
                        tokenizer: "keyword",
                        filter: ["lowercase", "asciifolding"],
                        char_filter: 'html_strip'
                    }
                }
           }
```

I have also tried char_filter by following James Healey charmap for sphinx for accented characters.
http://yob.id.au/2008/05/08/thinking-sphinx-and-unicode.html

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After playing around with it i resolved the issue. I had to change the behaviour of the default analyzer.

```
analyzer: {
                    default: {
                        tokenizer: "standard",
                        filter: ["standard", "lowercase", "asciifolding"]
                    },
                    text: {
                        tokenizer: "standard",
                        filter: ["standard", "lowercase"],
                        char_filter: 'html_strip'
                    },
                    sortable: {
                        tokenizer: "keyword",
                        filter: ["lowercase"],
                        char_filter: 'html_strip'
                    }
                }
```

Comment: When searching, did you need to convert queries containing accent-characters into ascii as well, or does this filter automatically run on search input?